# Can I programmatically convert between R.id ids and class of a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Suppose I have a Fragment called `Fragment MenuFragment` and it have R.id `android:id="@+id/MenuFragment"` inside nav_graph.xml

Question 1: Can I programmatically find R.id if I have just `MenuFragment.class` ?

Question 2: Can I programmatically get `MenuFragment.class` if I have just `R.id.MenuFragment` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No.  A fragment can have infinitely many ids.  If you have an instance of a fragment you can get its id, but you could have the same fragment in a dozen activities with a dozen different ids.  Heck, you can have a dozen copies in the same activity with a dozen ids.
2. This, yes.  If you use the id to get the actual instance of the fragment, you can then use .getClass() to get its class.